# IO woes when seeking sizes of directory contents?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell, and my goal today is to write a function `sizeOf :: FilePath -> IO Integer` (calculate the size of a file or folder), with the logic

- If `path` is a file, `System.Directory.getFileSize path`
- If `path` is a directory, get a list of its contents, recursively run this function on them, and `sum` the results
- If it's something other than a file or directory, `return 0`

Here's how I'd implement it in Ruby, to illustrate (Ruby notes: `map`'s argument is the equivalent of `\d -> size_of d`, `reduce :+` is `foldl (+) 0`, any function ending `?` returns a bool, returns are implicit):

```
def size_of path
  if File.file? path
    File.size path
  elsif File.directory? path
    Dir.glob(path + '/*').map { |d| size_of d }.reduce :+
  end
end
```

Here's my crack at it in Haskell:

```
  sizeOf :: FilePath -> IO Integer
  sizeOf path =
    do
      isFile <- doesFileExist path
      if isFile then
        getFileSize path
      else do
        isDir <- doesDirectoryExist path
        if isDir then
          sum $ map sizeOf $ listDirectory path
        else
          return 0
```

I know where my problem is. `sum $ map sizeOf $ listDirectory path`, where `listDirectory path` returns an `IO [FilePath]` and not a `FilePath`. But... I can't really imagine any solution solving this. `<$>` instead of `$` was the first thing that came to mind, since `<$>` I understood to be something that let a function of `a -> b` become a `Context a -> Context b`. But... I guess IO isn't like that?

I spent about two hours puzzling over the logic there. I tried it on other examples. Here's a relevant discovery that threw me: if `double = (*) 2`, then `map double [1,2,3] == [2,4,6]`, but `map double <$> [return 1, return 2, return 3] == [[2],[4],[6]]`... it wraps them in a list. I think that's what happening to me but I'm way out of my depth.

Comment: `But... I guess IO isn't like that?` Well, `IO` is a monad and therefore a functor so it is exactly like that but what you are looking for is probably `(>>=)` - a way to chain monadic computations. Just don't go reading monad tutorials! Dig into some haskell book.

Comment: `map double <$> [1,2,3]` is a type error unless you've done something very strange.

Comment: Oh good catch @DanielWagner. I meant to write `map double <$> [return 1, return 2, return 3]`. I had heard that `return` wrapped a value in the `IO` context so I was using that to try and test operations on `IO Integer`s. But I think I was confused, `return x` seems to make a `Monad x`, and only an `IO x` if you're inside a do-block? Maybe I've hit the limit of what I can learn without getting into monads (which my teacher advised to leave until last)...

Comment: You know waht `<-` and `do` and `return` do, why not try  them in the `then` branch?

Comment: What you will do when someone change file-type after you check? I think this approach is not good (on Ruby too).

Comment: @freestyle It's probably not a good solution for actually measuring sizes, I'm not going to actually use it. I just set it as an exercise for myself as Haskell practice.

Comment: @GreenTriangle, another way maybe `sizeOf pth = `getFileSize pth <|> listDirectory pth >>= fmap sum . mapM sizeOf <|> return 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd need

```
sum <$> (listDirectory path >>= mapM sizeOf)
```

Explanation:

- The idea to use `sum` over an `IO [Integer]` is ok, so we need to get such a thing.
- `listDirectory path` gives us `IO [FilePath]`, so we need to pass each file path to `sizeOf`. This is what `>>=` together with `mapM` does.
- Note that `map` alone would give us `[IO Integer]` that is why we need `mapM`

Comment: forgive me, but listDirectory isn't recursive?

Answer (score 1):

how about (using Control.Monad.Extra):

```
du :: FilePath -> IO Integer
du path = ifM (doesFileExist path)
              (getFileSize path) $
              ifM (doesDirectoryExist path)
                  (sum <$> (listDirectory path >>= mapM (du . 
                             (addTrailingPathSeparator path ++))))
                  (return 0)
```

I believe you need to add the path to the output of `listDirectory` for successful recursive descent as `listDirectory` only returns filenames without the path, which is required for the subsequent calls to du.

The type of `ifM` is probably obvious, but is `ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a`